# How to create select statements that include averages in sqlplus

Tags: sql, database

I am very new to answering queries and using sql language, so I am having a hard time answering this one query.

The exact wording of it is: "Print the player_id and average points scored of players who scored an average of points that is greater than the average of points scored in arena 1."

This query is very confusing and I don't quite understand what I need to enter into my server to pull up the information it wants.

Here is the table that I have to use and it is named team_player_arena:

```
 TEAM_ID  PLAYER_ID   ARENA_ID     POINTS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1         20
         1          1          4         17
         2          3          1         32
         2          3          2         22
         2          3          3         13
         2          3          4         25
         2          3          5          6
         2          3          6         14
         2          3          7         18
         2          5          2         11
         3          3          1         20
         3          4          2          5
         4          6          3         23
         4          6          7         18
         5          2          2         24
         5          2          4         10
         5          5          5         25
         5          5          7         16
         5          6          2         24
         5          1          4         33
         5          3          4         31
         5          4          4         26
         5          5          4         14
         5          6          4          5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I understood as you want the list of players and their average score, Who has their average score above average score of arena 1

```
  (SELECT player_id, avg(points)
      FROM player_table, 
     GROUP BY player_id  
      Having avg(points) > (SELECT avg(points) 
                              from player_table 
                             where arena_id =1 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much !